# How to create box around selected image on GUI

Tags: python, excel, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

My GUI is a slideshow of images and there is a certain correct image on each page of the slideshow. The correct image is the top-left triangle, heart balloon, the circle, and the hippo. I am completely new to python so I have been struggling with how to create box around the selected image when a user is using the slideshow. This box forms around the correct or the incorrect image, whichever is pressed. To further explain, this includes inserting a box around an image based on where the user clicks but it does not say whether the image selected is the correct image or not. Thank you for your help

[image]

[image]

```py
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageDraw
import tkinter as tk
import PIL.ImageTk
import csv
from PIL import Image

MAX_HEIGHT = 500
# height of the window (dimensions of the image)

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, imageData, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.clickStatus = tk.StringVar()
        self.loadedImages = dict()
        self.master.title('Slideshow')
        fram = tk.Frame(self)
        tk.Button(fram, text="Previous Image", command=self.prev).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(fram, text="  Next Image  ", command=self.next).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Label(fram, textvariable=self.clickStatus, font='Helvetica 18 bold').pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        # inside or outside 
        fram.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.imageLabel = tk.Label(self)
        # drawing the image on the label
        self.imageData = imageData
        self.currentIndex = 0
        # start from 0th image
        self.__loadImage__()
        self.imageLabel.bind("<Button-1>", self.clicked_evt)
        # when you click button, it opens event of clicked_evt
        self.imageLabel.pack()
        self.pack()

    def clicked_evt(self, evt):
        x, y = evt.x, evt.y
        imgData = self.loadedImages[self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['image_file']]
        (l, t), (r,b) = imgData['lt'], imgData['rb']
        if t<=y<=b and l<=x<=r:
            ##self.clickStatus.set('inside')
            print('Inside')
        else:
            ##self.clickStatus.set('outside')
            print('Outside')


    def __loadImage__(self):
        if self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['image_file'] not in self.loadedImages:

            self.im = PIL.Image.open(self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['image_file'])
    
            ratio = MAX_HEIGHT/self.im.height
        # ratio divided by existing height -> to get constant amount
            height, width = int(self.im.height*ratio), int(self.im.width * ratio)
            # calculate the new h and w and then resize next
            self.im = self.im.resize((width, height))
            lt = (int(self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['left']*ratio), int(self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['top']*ratio))
            rb = (int(self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['right']*ratio), int(self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['bottom']*ratio))
            # modifying new ratios with new height and width 
        #shape = [lt, rb]
            # print(shape)
            #img1 = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(self.im) 
            #img1.rectangle(shape, outline ="red")            
            if self.im.mode == "1": 
                self.img = PIL.ImageTk.BitmapImage(self.im, foreground="white")
            else:              
                self.img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
            imgData = self.loadedImages.setdefault(self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['image_file'], dict())
            imgData['image'] = self.img
            imgData['lt'] = lt
            imgData['rb'] = rb
        # for next and previous so it loads the same image adn don't do calculations again
        self.img = self.loadedImages[self.imageData[self.currentIndex]['image_file']]['image']
        self.imageLabel.config(image=self.img, width=self.img.width(), height=self.img.height())

    def prev(self):
        self.currentIndex = (self.currentIndex+len(self.imageData) - 1 ) % len(self.imageData)
        self.__loadImage__()
    # here if i go to the first one and press back, goes to last, round robbin

    def next(self):
        self.currentIndex = (self.currentIndex + 1) % len(self.imageData)
        self.__loadImage__()
    # here if i go to the last one and press next, goes to first, round robbin

def loadData(fname):
    with open(fname, mode='r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        data = [dict(row) for row in reader]
    for row in data:
        row['top'], row['bottom'], row['left'], row['right'] = int(row['top']),int(row['bottom']),int(row['left']),int(row['right'])
    return data          
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = loadData('bounding_box.csv')
    app = App(data)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you simply want to draw a rectangle around an image when it is clicked (explanation in code comments):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# below code is used to create images, you can also load them from a file if you need
mode = 'RGB'
size = (150, 150)
color_lst = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
# best to get all the images for the slide in a single list for further easier workings
img_lst = [Image.new(mode, size, color) for color in color_lst]


# selecting function that will be called when user clicks on image
def select(id_):
    canvas.create_rectangle(canvas.bbox(id_), width=5)
    
    # here you will put other code to be executed after
    # user clicks on the image like going to the next frame or sth
    
    # additionally you could use this if you want the other rectangles to disappear
    # but kinda pointless if you will switch frames and stuff
    # for canvas_id in canvas_images:
    #     if canvas_id == id_:
    #         continue
    #     canvas.create_rectangle(canvas.bbox(canvas_id), width=5, outline='white')


root = Tk()

# here create a photoimage list from the above image list
photo_lst = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(image) for image in img_lst]

# create canvas
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

# set the coordinates for the four images
coordinates = [(100, 100), (300, 100), (100, 300), (300, 300)]
# create the images and append their id to a list
canvas_images = [
    canvas.create_image(pos[0], pos[1], image=photo) for pos, photo in zip(coordinates, photo_lst)
]

# bind the ids from `canvas_images` to being clicked and execute simple drawing method
for c_img in canvas_images:
    canvas.tag_bind(
        c_img, '<Button-1>', lambda e, i=c_img: select(i)
    )

root.mainloop()
```